# Prove that, for all positive integers $x$ and $y$, $\sqrt{ xy} \leq \frac{x + y}{2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-explanation

Help I'm really stuck on a proof question:

Prove that, for all positive integers for $x$ and $y$, $\sqrt{ xy} \leq \frac{x + y}{2}$

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Math SX! Do  you know the `AM-GM` inequality?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray*}
(\sqrt{x}- \sqrt{y})^2 \geq 0
\end{eqnarray*}
and now do a little bit of algebra.

Comment: Oh I see! So you expand the brackets and rearrange?

Comment: That's right. Move the $-2 \sqrt{xy}$ to the RHS and divide by $2$.

Answer (score 4):

Start with $(\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{y})^2 \geq 0$.